# How to stop sublime text from adding a new extra line at the end?

Tags: macos, sublime-text-3, sublime-text, whitespace

I'm on OS X and using Sublime Text 3 and it's adding a newline at the end of document after I press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, which I don't want.

I have already added below line in Sublime Text user settings:

```
"ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": false,
```

But the problem is still there. Here is the recorded video of the problem:

[image: add line on save]

Comment: What plugins do you have installed? It's possible one of them is adding the newline...